# IDNA does not round-trip

Tags: python, idn, punycode

I have some IDNA encoded strings that I cannot decode. In Python, I try `u"xn--grohandel-shop-2fb".decode("idna")` and get the error "IDNA does not round-trip". The same for `"xn--sottmqqo5-lgbe9b7no0hmz9u"`.

I'm stumped, and Googling the error doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 5):

The error "IDNA does not round-trip" means that the module gets a different result when decoding and encoding the string.

By looking at the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/encodings/idna.py) for Python's IDNA module, the error "IDNA does not round-trip" is raised on line 139 if the module can't recreate the input. In the decode function the input is split by dots and every part is converted in `toUnicode`. There the text is decoded, but before the result is returned it encodes the result and compares it with the input and raises the error if it isn't the same: "it doesn't round-trip" or `encode(decode(text)) != text`.

In the error message you also get the two strings that it tried to compare, in the first example you get:

```
UnicodeError: ('IDNA does not round-trip', 'xn--grohandel-shop-2fb', 'grosshandel-shop')
```

You get the error because it has converted `ß` in "großhandel-shop" to `ss` in "grosshandel-shop". [The `ß` character was added to the `.de`-tld late 2010](http://www.denic.de/en/denic-in-dialogue/press-releases/press/2981.html?cHash=f05e172ceb), so this is a bug. Before the change `ß` was supposed to be changed to `ss`.

Your second example is probably corrupt, because it converts to: "đsottĤmqĐqǗoĔ⢠5"

Comment: xn--grohandel-shop-2fb has been correctly encoded by IDNA 2008 (which is correct in Germany/DENIC since a while). Your Python very likely tries to decode it using the old IDNA 2003, which doesn't know 'ß'.

see https://www.denic.de/en/know-how/idn-domains/